# SQL Server generate data using some data in table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Suppose that we have a table in SQL Server that stores shifts for doctors, so instead of storing explicit dates we are using weekdays, the table looks like this

```
ShiftId  Day    DoctorId    FromTime      ToTime
--------------------------------------------------
1        SUN    1           08:00:00      16:00:00
2        MON    1           09:00:00.00   14:00:00
3        TUE    1           09:00:00.00   15:00:00
4        WED    1           10:00:00.00   17:00:00
5        THU    1           13:00:00.00   18:00:00
```

I want to create a select statement to generate explicit dates by using data stored in this table

**Example**

suppose I want to generate dates between `Sunday 19th February 2017` to `Tuesday 28th February 2017`, the output should be like this

```
DoctorId    Date                Day     FromTime    ToTime
------------------------------------------------------------
1           '02-19-2017'        SUN     08:00:00    16:00:00
1           '02-20-2017'        MON     09:00:00    14:00:00
1           '02-21-2017'        TUE     09:00:00    15:00:00
1           '02-22-2017'        WED     10:00:00    17:00:00
1           '02-23-2017'        THU     13:00:00    18:00:00
1           '02-26-2017'        SUN     08:00:00    16:00:00
1           '02-27-2017'        MON     09:00:00    14:00:00
1           '02-28-2017'        TUE     09:00:00    15:00:00
```

**Explanation**

Times generated for these dates correspond to days stored in our table for example the time generated for `'02-19-2017'` in the first row is `08:00:00`    `16:00:00` because `'02-19-2017'` is Sunday, and the time generated for `'02-20-2017'` in the second row is `09:00:00   14:00:00` because `'02-20-2017'` is Monday and so on.

As you may notice no dates generated for `24th February FRI` and `25th February SAT`, because we don't store `Friday` and `Saturday` in our table

Can we write a query in T-SQL that returns this result?

Comment: Do you need this as SQL?  Would it not be easier to manipulate the data in your Application before displaying it?

Comment: So here should i have to assume that you give two input variable `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` using which i have to generate "Date" column right ???

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith the reason I want it in SQL that the generated data will be joined with another table, so it wouldn't be efficient in code as SQL

Comment: @KrishnrajRana yes exactly `DateFrom` and `DateTo` will be supplied as parameters to the SQL query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use your From/To input parameters to generate a calendar on the fly in a recursive CTE, then join that to your shift table based on the weekday value.

```
DECLARE @Shift TABLE (ShiftID INT, [Day] VARCHAR(3), DoctorId INT, FromTime TIME, ToTime TIME)
INSERT INTO @Shift 
VALUES (1,'SUN',1,'08:00:00','16:00:00'),
       (2,'MON',1,'09:00:00.00','14:00:00'),
       (3,'TUE',1,'09:00:00.00','15:00:00'),
       (4,'WED',1,'10:00:00.00','17:00:00'),
       (5,'THU',1,'13:00:00.00','18:00:00')

DECLARE @D1 DATE, @D2 DATE
SET @D1 = '2017-02-19'
SET @D2 = '2017-02-28'

;WITH Calendar AS
(
    SELECT @D1 AS [DateVal], LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@D1),3) AS [DWName]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,DateVal), LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(DAY,1,DateVal)),3)
    FROM Calendar
    WHERE DateVal<@D2
)


SELECT S.DoctorId, C.DateVal, S.[Day], S.FromTime, S.ToTime
FROM @Shift S
JOIN Calendar C ON S.[Day]=C.DWName
```

Answer (score 0):

use a calendar CTE, join to it

```
with DateCTE as
(
select @DateFrom as Date1
union
select dateadd('DD',1,Date1)
from DateCTE
where Date1 < @DateTo
)
select D1.*,
       datename('DW',Date1) as Day
       FromTime,
       ToTime
from DateCTE D1
left join MyTable M2
  on datename('DW',Date1) like M2.Day
where datename('DW',Date1) not like 'Fri%' 
and datename('DW',Date1) not like 'Sat%'
```

Comment: actually we can't say explicitly in code to ignore `FRI` and `SAT` because we can't expect this data, this data might be changed later

Answer (score 0):

I think that using SQL for this kind of task is a bad idea due to using a lot of logical operations. Using a C# function should be more efficient.

Using SQL or C# would be the same logical solution:

1 - Create a temporary table that will keep your result.

2 - Loop over your date from starting date to end date. For each date get the DAY part. From the DAY part, get your field FromTime and ToTime. Insert the result on your temporary table.

3 - Return the temporary table (Or Select and destroy it).

Comment: You're right but the problem that I want to create SQL query that I want to use the generated data to be joined with another table

Comment: Then just keep the temporary table and join on it. You don't care if C# complete your temporary table in the first place. The problem of using C# would be the communication of your temporary table name (either you put a static one or use dynamic SQL on your join query).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a calendar table in your database.  For this purpose, you can use recursive CTEs or a number table to almost the same effect:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master.spt_values
     )
select dd.doctorid, d.dte, s.day, s.fromtime, s.totime
from (select dateadd(day, n.n, @startdate) as dte
      from n
      where dateadd(day, n.n, @startdate) <= @enddate
     ) d cross join
     (select distinct doctorid from shifts
     ) dd join
     shifts s
     on upper(left(datename(wd, d.dte), 3)) = s.day and
        ss.doctorid = d.doctorid;
```

This is a bit tricky.  The idea is to generate the dates (which is pretty easy using the number table).  Then do a `cross join` with the doctors, so all doctors have all dates.  Finally, join back to the `shifts` table, to get the matching records (if any) and the appropriate times.

Note that this version will work for multiple doctors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @STARTDate date = '02-19-2017', @ToDate date = '02-27-2017'

;WITH myCTE AS
(
    SELECT @STARTDate AS MyDate, 1 AS iID
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,MyDate), iID + 1
              FROM   myCTE 
              WHERE  MyDate < @ToDate
)
SELECT * FROM YourTable
JOIN myCTE on myCTE.iID = YourTable.ID
```